# Rational Sorgenfrey Plane is normal?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Z$ be the topological space generated by sets of the form $[q,r)$ where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove that $Z \times Z$ is normal.

My first attempt was to show that this is equivalent to the Sorgenfrey line, but it isn't. Is there a quick proof to show whether this is normal? Or does it follow directly analogously to the proof that $\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l$ is not normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z \times Z$ is indeed normal. To see this, observe that $Z$ is second countable and normal. In particular, $Z$ is regular. Thus, $Z\times Z$ is regular and second-countable. Finally, notice that a regular second-countable space is normal.

Comment: Note that a countable base is $\{[q,r):q,r \in \Bbb Q\}$.